# Validation not fired if I just clear an @OneToMany relation

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, jpa, merge

I'm facing a problem when updating an Entity using JPA 2.0 and Hibernate (I didn't test with other providers). Here Is my entity (cutted down for brevity):

```
@Entity
public class CriterioDefinicaoImpFederais implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="criterio_definicao_imp_federais", sequenceName="criterio_definicao_imp_federais")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="criterio_definicao_imp_federais", strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(length=100)
    @NotNull
    @TextoValido(min=1, max=100)
    private String descricao = "";

    //Other fields ommited

    @NotEmpty
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true, mappedBy="criterio")
    //Bidirectional association
    private List<GrupoCriterioImpFederais> grupos = new ArrayList<>();

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void addGrupo(GrupoCriterioImpFederais grupo) {
        grupo.setCriterio(this);
        this.grupos.add(grupo);
    }

    public void removerGrupo(GrupoCriterioImpFederais grupo) {
        grupos.remove(grupo);
        grupo.setCriterio(null);
    }

    //Other methods ommited
}
```

Supose I try to persist one new CriterioDefinicaoImpFederais instance. Validation works well, including the @NotEmpty on field grupos.
Then I load the instance persisted, clear the grupos list (calling removerGrupo) and try to update (using the JPA 2.0 merge) the instance.

At this point, the validation for grupos (@NotEmpty) is not fired. BUT, if I change another field of CriterioDefinicaoImpFederais (like descricao for example), all validations are fired including the validations for grupos.

Is this the correct behavior? Or what am I missing? Is there a way to fire the validations?

Ps: I've tried to call flush after merge, without success.

Code to load and update objects:
To load I use the following hql:

```
//This is critRepo.porId
String sql = "select distinct c from CriterioDefinicaoImpFederais c "
        + "  join fetch c.licenca "
        + "  join fetch c.grupos g "
        + "where "
        + "  c.id = :id ";
```

This is the code executed after the object is persisted:

```
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    CriterioDefinicaoImpFederais outro = critRepo.porId(criterio.getId());
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.clear();
    outro.removerGrupo(outro.getGrupos().get(0));
    outro.removerGrupo(outro.getGrupos().get(0));
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    //This method calls merge
    critRepo.salvar(outro);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, can you post the code where you are retrieving and updating the entity?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't verified this, but it might be because you aren't accessing the value through an setter that adheres to the Java Bean Specification.

Try if you set it to a new empty collection through a normal setter.

Comment: @Jean thanks for answering. I created a new method `setGrupos` and called `setGrupos(new ArrayList<>());` and got the same behavior.